# MS Graph and AAD Graph Rest api works fine in Local machine debugging but getting forbidden response after publishing to azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on some piece of code where I am fetching the logged in users profile pic and display name from AAD Graph API and Microsoft Graph respectively.

The code is working fine when I'm debugging locally, but I'm getting a Forbidden error after publishing to an Azure Web App service.

The app service is enabled with Azure Authentication and the apps are registered with App registration to use the Graph features.

```
result = await authContext
    .AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/",
        credential,
        new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", resultpic.AccessToken);

HttpRequestMessage request =
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);

HttpResponseMessage response =
    await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Try disable the azure authentication and let your app controls the authentication process  .

Comment: Your code is fine. Just like Nan Yu said, you needn't enable app service authentication if you deal with the authentication yourself. If this doesn't solve your issue, you can provide the detailed error message here.

Comment: When are you getting your 403? Are getting it when you attempt to retreive a token or are you getting it when you're using the token for graph API? Is there any additional logging you can provide?

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu and Tony Ju for  the comments. I tried your way by disabling the authentication in appservice but still cannot able to get the success response. Getting 403 forbidden as response.

Comment: HI Ryan, I am getting 403 while calling this line HttpResponseMessage response =
    await client.SendAsync(request); This function is called at the viewcomponent call function. I tried logging the erro rmessage and thsi i sthe message that I am getting from Http response. ie the forbidden message.

Comment: @AnurajRajagopal In your code snippet, what's `requestUrl` set to? Also, I don't see you using `result` here, so I'm assuming are you getting `resultpic` the same way, right? Assuming that's the case, does it have a [valid](https://jwt.ms) token?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you already have disabled app service authentication and enabled Azure AD as identity provider like below:

[image]

To easily grab the photo via Azure AD, for now, you can use this URL template:

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version={version}
```

Below code below assumes you already have an authenticated user, with a token. This is a simplistic example; you'll want to change the return value to suit your needs, add error checking, etc.

```
const string ThumbUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{0}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6";

// Attempts to retrieve the thumbnail image for the specified user, with fallback.
// Returns: Fully formatted string for supplying as the src attribute value of an img tag.
private string GetUserThumbnail(string userId)
{
    string thumbnail = "some base64 encoded fallback image";
    string mediaType = "image/jpg"; // whatever your fallback image type is
    string requestUrl = string.Format(ThumbUrl, userId);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetToken());
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Read the response as a byte array
        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // The headers will contain information on the image type returned
        mediaType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;

        // Encode the image string
        thumbnail = Convert.ToBase64String(responseBody);
    }

    return $"data&colon;{mediaType};base64,{thumbnail}";
}

// Factored out for use with other calls which may need the token
private string GetToken()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"] == null ? string.Empty : HttpContext.Current.Session["Token"].ToString();
}
```

Please also ensure that your Azure AD app have the right permission set.

Hope it helps.